# compute the waiting time for a given pattern with Kac's lemma

Tags: pr.probability

Suppose we are tossing a banlanced coin, and we want to compute the expectation of the waiting time for the pattern HTHTH.

Kac's lemma is a result in ergodic theory which states that, for a ergodic transformation and a positive measurable set $A$, $$\int_A n_A d\mu =1$$
Here $n_A$ denote the first return time of the points in $A$ undet $T$.

I wonder how to use Kac's lemma to compute the waiting time, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: This question appears in David Williams' book Probability with Martingales (under the title "The Abracadabra Problem") - the question being how long before a monkey on a typewriter spells out the word abracadabra (the answer is not $26^11$).

Comment: This is a problem in combinatorics, not probability. To compute the waiting time, you will want to compute the autocorrelation of the sequence, or the autocorrelation polynomial. See http://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/lectures/lectures13/AA08-Strings.pdf

Comment: Douglas, I do not understand the reason for your decisive tone. Has the coin not been balanced, would it still not be a problem in probability? what if the coin tosses are a Markov chain, or a more general stochastic process?

Comment: I mean that the natural technique for solving this problem is to understand the combinatorics of strings, e.g., the generating function for the number of strings of length $n$ not containing HTHTH can be expressed in terms of the autocorrelation polynomial of HTHTH, yet this question was tagged probability instead of combinatorics. For an unbalanced coin or Markov chain, you can still use the combinatorics of strings. I don't know what you are suggesting for a non-Markov stochastic process. It sounds like that would be a completely different question.

Comment: Perhaps I just don't know how to do this with purely probabilistic techniques. If you have such a method, I'd appreciate seeing it.

Comment: Douglas, there is a classical probabilistic way to do this using martingales (as Anthony pointed out). It is described in section 17.3.2 of the book "Markov chains and mixing times" by Levin, Peres and Wilmer, which can be found at: http://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf


Comment: That's a nice argument, thanks. That does show how the autocorrelation polynomial arises within probability. 

Comment: As explained by others, Kac's lemma describes the mean return time to some word w starting from w. On the other hand, for the hitting time of w one starts from the empty word. Hence the hitting time is almost surely at least as large as the return time, likewise for their means. The mean hitting and return times coincide if and only if no terminal strict subword of w is an initial subword of w. For example, for w=HHHTT they coincide but for w=HTHTH they do not since HTH is both terminal and initial.

Answer (score 2):

A little too long for a comment, but not an answer.

You can model this as a Markov Chain (in this case, a random walk on a directed graph) as follows. Intuitively, consider an infinite sequence of coin tosses, and take a sliding window of successive 5 outcomes. Suppose the first 5 tosses gave HHHHH. This is the starting state. Now suppose you get T. So the state is HHHHT. And now you get an H, so the state is HHHTH, etc.

Formally, consider all patterns on 5 coin tosses, so there are 32 of them. These are the states of the MC. Any state has two possible transitions of probability 1/2, obtained by appending either H or T to the end and removing the first coin toss. So HHTHT can transition to HTHTH or HTHTT with probability 1/2. So this gives the Markov Chain M. Think of the corresponding directed graph G, where each edge has the probability of transition. There are 32 vertices, 32 X 2 = 64 edges (two from each vertex), with each edge of probability 1/2. Each vertex also has two incoming edges.

Note that the uniform distribution is the stationary distribution.

So your question becomes: starting from the uniform distribution on (vertices of) G, what is the expected time to reach state HTHTH?

I don't see how Kac's lemma help. Kac's lemma tells us that if you started from HTHTH, then the expected return time is exactly 32 steps.

One can show: if we take 32 steps, then the expected number of occurrences of HTHTH is exactly 1. This is by linearity of expectation and the fact that the stationary distribution is uniform. If one starts from the uniform distribution, the probability of hitting HTHTH is 1/32. This is true for all steps, since the walk remains in the uniform distribution.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if this would qualify for you as a solution using Kac's lemma, but here it goes ...

The elementary version of Kac's lemma for an irreducible Markov chain with unique stationary distribution $\pi$ states that the expected return time of each state $a$ is $1/\pi(a)$.  This follows from the ergodic theory version if you consider the (one-sided) Markov shift associated to the Markov chain and look at the return time of the cylinder set $\{(\omega_i)_{i\geq 0}: \omega_0=a\}$.

As Sesh mentioned, you can formulate your problem in terms of a Markov chain whose states are all the words of length $5$ on $\{\mathtt{H},\mathtt{T}\}$ with transitions $w_0w_1w_2w_3w_4\to w_1w_2w_3w_4\mathtt{H}$ and  $w_0w_1w_2w_3w_4\to w_1w_2w_3w_4\mathtt{T}$ of equal probability from each state $w_0w_1w_2w_3w_4$.  This is the $5$-bit *[shift register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_register)* chain.  The stationary distribution is uniform, so if $T_u$ denotes the first time $>0$ the shift register is in state $u:=\mathtt{HTHTH}$, we have $\mathbb{E}_u T_u=32$, where $\mathbb{E}_u$ is the expected value if the shift register is initialized with $u$.

However, you ask for $\mathbb{E}_\varnothing T_u$, where I am using $\mathbb{E}_\varnothing$ to to denote the expectation if the initial state has no overlap with $u$ (or if the shift register is empty, if you will).

Conditioning on the first two coin flips we get
\begin{align}
   \mathbb{E}_uT_u &= 
      \frac{1}{2}(1+\mathbb{E}_{\mathtt{H}}T_u) + \frac{1}{4}2 +
      \frac{1}{4}(2+\mathbb{E}_\varnothing T_u) \;.
\end{align}
The first term is for when the first flip comes up $\mathtt{H}$, the second for when the first two flips turn out $\mathtt{TH}$ (hence returning to $u$) and the third for if the first two flips are $\mathtt{TT}$. I am writing $\mathbb{E}_{\mathtt{H}}$ for the expectation if the initial state has the form $w_0w_1w_2w_3 \mathtt{H}$ and the only possible overlap with $u$ is with the last bit.

A similar equation can be written for $\mathbb{E}_\varnothing T_u$ by conditioning on the first flip:
\begin{align}
   \mathbb{E}_\varnothing T_u &=
      \frac{1}{2}(1+\mathbb{E}_{\mathtt{H}}T_u) +
      \frac{1}{2}(1+\mathbb{E}_{\varnothing}T_u) 
\end{align}

Solving the two equations for $\mathbb{E}_\varnothing T_u$ we get
\begin{align}
   \mathbb{E}_\varnothing T_u &=
      \frac{1}{3} (4\cdot \mathbb{E}_u T_u - 2) = \frac{4\times 32 - 2}{3} = 42 \;.
\end{align}

However, I hesitate to call this a solution using Kac's lemma, because the proof of Kac's lemma (the elementary version) is as simple, and uses the same kind of conditioning.